# using ActiveModelSerializers in rails how do I set a serializer from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in a rails app, I want to know how I can select which serializer to use from a view.

I have 2 serializers **LimitedQuestionSerializer** and **QuestionSerializer**, the limited  one returns a limited result set.

Here is my **question.haml** view

```
- cache ['inline-question', question, preview?] do
  - opts = preview? ? { preview: true } : {}
  = react_component 'Aeon.Components.MountInlineQuestion', { 
data: ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(question) }
```

So I want to explicitly call the limited Serializer instead of the default, e.g.

```
LimitedQuestionSerializer.new(question)
```

According to the docs this is correct but when I do this I just get back the serialized json structure, but all the data is null.

```
serializer = SomeSerializer.new(resource, serializer_options)
```

Comment: Normally this should work, not sure where the problem is, could you both update your serializer & react component here?